# Filtering for dates less than or or equal to 9 months in the future in an Access query

Tags: date, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Once a week I need to run a report where I query an Access database for any product that will expire in 9 months or less. The way they want it calculated is to take the date 9 months into the future and return anything that expires at the end of that month or sooner. If it were simply 270 days or less, I'd have no problem. (I'd also have no problem if I could do it in Excel, but that's not an option for now).

I came up with a solution that works every month of the year, unless it happens to be March (more specifically between March 6th and April 5th).

```
    < DateValue(Month(Date()+270)+1 & "/1/" & Year(Date()+270))
```

So basically I'm:

- adding 270 days to today's date
- extracting the resulting month
- adding 1 to the month
- putting it back together as a text string so I can use < the 1st of the following month
- for the year, I'm using the year from the date +270 days so I don't end up using the current year by accident

The trouble is that for the date range above (which I unhappily discovered  today), I land in December when I add 270 days, so the following month is in a different year. As a result, my report only produced items that already expired.

In other words, on March 5th, I would have needed a list of everything expiring prior to December 1, but on March 6th, I need everything before January 1 of the next year.

Is there a more effective way to do this that avoids this issue? I thought of using

Comment: *"I thought of using"* - If you thought of using the [DateAdd](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) function, as in `DateAdd("m", 9, Date())` then that would be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have had DateDiff in mind, and it can be used:

```
Where DateDiff("m", Date(), [YourDateField]) Between 0 And 9
```

However, that will ignore an index you might have on [YourDateField].

This, however, will include products that expired previously in the current month.

The alternative is DateSerial as Hans showed but he forgot that in SQL Date() must be used and that only those products that will expire should be listed:

```
 Where [YourDateField] Between Date() And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 10, 0)
```

Comment: I added those missing parentheses.  Thanks.

Comment: This worked great. Since I haven't really gotten into actual SQL yet, I used  /DateDiff("m",Date(),[Expiration_Date])<10/ directly in the query. This does include the already expired items, but they explained they wanted to keep that in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateSerial Function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/DateSerial-Function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) to compute the future date you need.

Here is a demonstration in the Access Immediate window which computes the date 9 months from today:

```vb
? Date
3/6/2015 
? DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 9, Day(Date))
12/6/2015
```

However, as I understand your requirement, you actually want dates from that entire month.  In that case you can compute the first of the month which is 10 months from today and ask for everything less than that date.

```vb
? DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 10, 1)
1/1/2016
```

You can include that expression in your query like this ...

```sql
WHERE expire_date < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 10, 1)
```

Comment: This was helpful, but the other answer was a little simpler. I will come back to this so I can understand the SQL better, though. Thanks!